# After installing Jenkins Role Strategy Plugin - all logins fail

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I'm playing with a new install Jenkins 1.561, running as a Windows Service on a 64-bit Windows 7 Professional (SP1).

I'd installed without a problem, enabled security, configured it to use Jenkins' own user database, and created a few users.

Then I installed the Role Strategy Plugin.  With it installed, I was unable to log in as any user.  When I disabled the Role Strategy Plugin, my logins worked again.

Is this a known bug?  Or is there something I am missing, to get the permissions to propagate correctly?

The documentation I was using (https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Role+Strategy+Plugin) said to set "Security Realm" to "Delegate to servlet container". Is this incorrect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you don't need to change "Security Realm", only change "Authorization".

The documentation was just showing the default options. You said you already had "Jenkins' own user database", keep that

Comment: The documentation does say it's just showing the default options, it says "Activate by doing this". The documentation could be a bit clearer.

Comment: I did the same, and going back is to edit config.xml, and set  <securityRealm class="hudson.security.HudsonPrivateSecurityRealm">

Answer (score 0):

Open $jenkins_home/config.xml

Under string

```
Update the following tag with your username.
    <assignedSIDs>
      <sid>admin</sid>
    </assignedSIDs>
```